# nodSelector for "helm_release" resource in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, nodes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Terraform for deploying **cert-manager** and **ambassador**.

Trying to understand how to use **nodeSelector** in terraform deployment and assign the helm chart I'm using for both services to a specific group node I have (using a label with key and value to assign)

```
resource "helm_release" "cert_manager" {
  namespace        = var.cert_manager_namespace
  name             = "cert-manager"
  repository       = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart            = "cert-manager"
  version          = var.cert_manager_release_version
  create_namespace = true
  count            = var.enable

set {
  name = "controller."
}
set {
  name = "controller.nodeselector"
  value = ""
}
set {
  name  = "installCRDs" # Should only happen on the first attempt
  value = "true"
}

set {
  name  = "securityContext.enabled"
  value = "true"
}
```

Thie example above is me trying to assign it.
Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If Your nodeSelector location in values.yaml looks like this:

```
controller:
    nodeSelector: {}
```

You should be setting it up this way:

```
set {
    name = "controller.nodeSelector.dedicated"
    value = "workloads"
}
```

Where **dedicated** is key and **workloads** is value.